# How do I reconnect IBActions when the little circle has disappeared?

Tags: swift, xcode, iboutlet, xcode-storyboard, ibaction

I'm new to learning Swift (and using stackoverflow) so I'm not 100% sure what I've done but I opened my Xcode file and all of my IBActions no longer have the little circle next to them in the number column and I now have 14 errors and I'm not sure how to reconnect them?
[ViewController image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgtol.png)

My class and identity inspector are all linked as well.
[Shows that they are linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wocds.png)

Is there a way to connect it again without having to remake the IBA's as I have multiple buttons connected to one and it would just be a bit of a pain.

Thank you

Comment: It's because you have an extra or missing an opening { or closing } somewhere: Your code is broken, that's why.

Comment: @Larme Ahh I was so overwhelmed with all the errors that I didn't read them properly. Thank you!
Through your help I realised that I had moved my functions outside of my class due to an extra }